# how to parse string object without double quote in front in json

Tags: json, angular, typescript

i have an array in my angular applicaton for eg:

```
searchTerm : any[]
```

I have a textbox with a value {'state':'tn'} and want to push this to the searchTerm array. Currently i add this item to a service and then array as:

```
  private onItemAdded(event): void {
    const filter = JSON.parse('"' + event['value'] + '"');
    this.dataService.addFilter(filter);
  }
```

But it is storing as `"{'state':'tn'}"`

How can i parse this without double quotes in the front?

```
console.log('ADDED FILTER', event['value']);
```

here the value is printed as {'state':'value'}

but when assign to variable as below, it adds double quotes

```
let filter = event['value'];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

why you are using `parse`?, it is for converting from JSON to object, instead use `stringify` which will parse your object to `JSON`(string)

```js
const obj = "{'state':'tn'}";
let filter = JSON.stringify(obj);
filter = filter.slice(1, filter.length - 1);
console.log(filter);
```

Comment: but i am getting the value from textbox as "{'state':'california'}" even though i just added {'state':'california'}

Comment: @MukilDeepthi ah then you need to use `slice` or something similar, I have updated my answer, please check

Comment: but when i use the slice it comes as 'state':'tn'. the double quotes is not part of string it seems. not sure where it is added.

Comment: @MukilDeepthi did you use `JSON.stringify`, or better show me what you have tried